# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with canvas in js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid     #000000;">
</canvas>
<script src="pro checkers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
class Board {
    var ct = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = ct.getContext("2d");
    function Draw_board()
    {
        c.fillStyle = "rgb(220,220,220)";
        c.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
        c.fillStyle = "rgb(50,50,50)";
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                c.fillRect(i*150,j*150,75,75);
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                c.fillRect(i*150+75,j*150+75,75,75);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Pices {
    Update();
    var Pices = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""];
    var Face_pices = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""];
    function Update()
    {
        Draw_board();
        Draw_pices();
    }
    function Draw_pices()
    {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
        c.stroke();
    }
}
```

The error is where the canvas is defined in javascript here:

```
var ct = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = ct.getContext("2d");
```

It says:

pro checkers.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I am trying to make a checkers engine and this is the start but it is not working what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is way off. This doesn't really look like js. You can't just put statements in class.

Comment: The unexpected identifier is the `function` keyword. Remove it.